# Nested For Each Loop (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a xlsm file in order to open txt files(column D) with excel and change the sheet name as it was shown in column C. The user will choose the desired rows of column C and D with an InputBox. When I press the button, I can choose the rows without a problem and txt files are open on a seperate excel files. However, the name of all the sheets of the 3 opened txt files are the last one on column C "NeighON_WSMON". However, I would like that file at column D4 has the sheet name as from column C4 and so on. How can I achieve this? Lastly, how could I save that excel files into one excel file?
Thank you very much for your support on this.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myPath As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngName As Range
Dim cellName As Range

myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

'Show inputbox to user and  prompt for a cell range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell range:", _
Title:="Create sheets", _
Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)

'Show inputbox to user and  prompt for a cell range
Set rngName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell range:", _
Title:="Name sheets", _
Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)

'Iterate through cells in selected range
For Each cell In rng
    'Check if cell is not empty
    If cell <> "" Then        
        For Each cellName In rngName
            If cellName <> "" Then
            Set TxtFiles = Workbooks.Open(myPath & "\" & cell & ".txt")
            TxtFiles.Sheets(1).Name = cellName
            End If
        Next cellName
        'TxtFiles.Sheets(1).Name = "Tarrak"
        'TxtFiles.Sheets(1).Copy
        'NewBook.Worksheets.Add.Name = cell
    End If
'Continue with next cell in cell range
Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer:

You are iterating over your cells more often than you mean too, and are making 9 `workbooks.open()` calls where you mean to make 3. That is you iterate over `cell` and `cellName` to produce the following impact, in the following order.

```
Cell  CellName    Impact
-----+-----------+-----------------------------
[C3]  [D3]        Open D3, name as C3
[C3]  [D4]        Open D4, name as C3
[C3]  [D5]        Open D5, name as C3
[C4]  [D3]        Activate D3, re-name as C4
[C4]  [D4]        Activate D4, re-name as C4
[C4]  [D5]        Activate D5, re-name as C4
[C5]  [D3]        Activate D3, re-name as C5
[C5]  [D4]        Activate D4, re-name as C5
[C5]  [D5]        Activate D5, re-name as C5
```

To correct this, you should convert this to a singel for loop; This will require you to make sure that there is an equal number of values in `rng` and `rngName`.

---

## Longer Answer

I would suggest a couple of changes for this project. Firstly, I would recommend that you add the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference to your project so you can easily take advantage of the `FileSystemObject` type - this is absolutely wonderful for any time you need to handle File I/O.

My personal preference for using this is to add the line

```
Global fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

to the head of the document. There is no need to initiallize the object and it is accessible from all scopes.

I would then recommend that you break the action of opening and renaming the sheet of the txt file into its own function.

Just about the simplest version of this function would look something like

```
Private Function OpenTXTasWB(ByVal txtName As String, ByVal path As String, _
                             ByVal sheetName As String) As Excel.Workbook
            
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fso.BuildPath(path, txtName))
    Let wb.Worksheets(1).Name = sheetName
    Set OpenTXTasWB = wb

End Function
```

but you can easily modify this to make it have better error handling, or allow for optional arguments. Such a modified version would then look something like

```
Private Function OpenTXTasWB(ByVal txtName As String, _
                    Optional ByVal path As Variant, _
                    Optional ByVal sheetName As Variant) _
            As Excel.Workbook
    
    Dim wb      As Excel.Workbook, _
        bOldDA  As Boolean
    
    '' check for missing input and assign defaults (optional, but preferred)
    If IsMissing(path) Then Let path = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
    'If IsMissing(sheetName) Then Let sheetName = "default-value"       '' If you want a defualt name
    
    
    '' Error handling for bad inputs (optional, but preferred)

    ''  check for bad path var
    If Not TypeName(path) = "String" Then
        Call Err.Raise(Number:=13, Description:="function `OpenTXTasWB(txtName,[path],[sheetname])` expected `path` to " & _
                                                "be of type `string`, however type `" & TypeName(path) & "` was supplied.")
    ElseIf Not fso.FolderExists(path) Then
        Call Err.Raise(Number:=76, Description:="function `OpenTXTasWB(txtName,[path],[sheetname])` expected `path` to " & _
                                                "a valid directory, however, it was not found")
    End If
    
    ''  check for bad sheetname var
    If Not TypeName(sheetName) = "String" And Not IsMissing(sheetName) Then
        Call Err.Raise(Number:=13, Description:="function `OpenTXTasWB(txtName,[path],[sheetname])` expected `sheetname` to " & _
                                                "be of type `string`, however type `" & TypeName(sheetName) & "` was supplied.")
    End If
    
    '' check for a non-existant file
tryWithExt:
    If Not fso.FileExists(fso.BuildPath(path, txtName)) Then
        If Not InStr(1, StrReverse(txtName), ".") > 1 Then
            Let txtName = txtName & ".txt"
            GoTo tryWithExt
        End If
        Call Err.Raise(Number:=53, Description:="function `OpenTXTasWB(txtName,[path],[sheetname])` expected to find a flle " & _
                                                "at `" & fso.BuildPath(path, txtName) & "`, but none was found.")
    End If
    
    '' open the file as wb
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fso.BuildPath(path, txtName))
    
    '' set the name, iff a name was supplied
    If Not IsMissing(sheetName) Then Let wb.Worksheets(1).Name = sheetName
    
    '' output the wb
    Set OpenTXTasWB = wb

End Function
```

but whether or not you choose to implement the types of features is entirely up to you.

Either way you choose to set up the openning function, this will greatly simplify the major section of your demo. If you want to handle the workbooks individually, this would look something like

```
Public Sub demo()

    Dim rSheets As Excel.Range, _
        rSheet  As Excel.Range
    
    Set rSheets = Application.InputBox( _
            Prompt:="Please select the cell range:", _
            Title:="Create sheets", _
            Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    
    For Each rSheet In rSheets
        
        '' file to open is rsheet.offset(0,1)
        '' sheet name is rsheet.Offset(0,0)
        
        Set wb = OpenTXTasWB(txtName:=rSheet.Offset(0, 1), sheetName:=rSheet.Offset(0, 1))
            
    Next rSheet
    
End Sub
```

or if you want to keep ahold of the workbooks for later, it would look something more along the lines of the below.

```
Public Sub demo2()

    Dim rSheets As Excel.Range, _
        rSheet  As Excel.Range, _
        wbs()   As Excel.Workbook, _
        iter    As Long
    
    Set rSheets = Application.InputBox( _
            Prompt:="Please select the cell range:", _
            Title:="Create sheets", _
            Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    
    ReDim wb(1 To rSheets.Cells.Count)
    
    For iter = 1 To rSheets.Cells.Count Step 1
        Set rSheet = rSheets.Item(iter)

        Set wbs(iter) = OpenTXTasWB(txtName:=rSheet.Offset(0, 1), sheetName:=rSheet.Offset(0, 1))
        
    Next rSheet        

End Sub
```

Hope that helps!